# Running Jupyter notebook in Docker

Tags: python, docker, server, containers, jupyter-notebook

I want to run jupyter in docker container. I am not able to launch the jupyter notebook. When I copy paste the URL given in the terminal.. server cannot be reached.  Will appreciate any ideas to try

[image]

Comment: Did you open port 8888 in the firewall of the host?

Comment: I am using windows 10 and I have manually opened this port in the firewall. It did not help!

Answer (score 1):

You are forwarding port 8080 in the `docker run` call with `-p 8080:8080`.  But you also need to forward port 8888 by adding `-p 8888:8888`.  More specifically, you want to run:

```
docker -it -p 8080:8080 -p 8888:8888 jupyter/minimal-notebook
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing is Jupyter nootbook runs on port 8888. If you want to access the notebook on a diff port on your host you should map it like this -p 80:8888.

If you don't mind using the defaults, you should use run the following command.
Run this command: `docker run -p 8888:8888 jupyter/minimal-notebook`. Then

replace the host name in the url given in terminal with localhost like this 
`http://localhost:8888/\?token\=<TOKEN>\&token\=<TOKEN>`

This should work.

Note: If you map it to a diff port, you should replace it in the url you get in the terminal. Ex. `http://localhost:80/\?token\=<TOKEN>\&token\=<TOKEN>`

Comment: unfortunately, even after manually correcting the url, I could not reach the notebook. I suspect that the problem is somewhere else than the ports. Just thinking where could it be. I had Anaconda seperately installed outside docker. Jupiter works there.